# Infinite geometric series derivation problem

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, statistics

I don't understand how's the pointed portion of the second line derived. can anyone explain please.

[image]

Comment: They used the result that they show in blue.  You do know that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty a^k = \frac{a}{1-a}$ I hope?  How about the related formula for $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty ka^k$?  If your question is how to apply those results, it is as simple as renaming $x$ to $k$ and renaming $\frac{e^t}{2}$ to $a$.  If your question is where the results they applied came from in the first place, that can be found elsewhere on this site easily.

Comment: is there any formula for ka^k series from 1 to infinity ... @JMoravitz

Comment: @HimelMazumder See [How can I evaluate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)x^n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/30732) and the [questions linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/30732).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know $S_0=\sum_1^\infty a^k = \dfrac{a}{1-a}$ from the blue

Now consider $S_1=\sum_1^\infty k \,a^k$

You have $aS_1 = \sum_1^\infty a k \,a^k = \sum_1^\infty k \,a^{k+1} = \sum_2^\infty (k-1) \,a^{k} = \sum_1^\infty (k-1) \,a^{k} = S_1-S_0$

so $aS_1 =  S_1-S_0$ and thus $(1-a)S_1=S_0=\dfrac{a}{1-a}$

giving $S_1=\dfrac{a}{(1-a)^2} = \dfrac{1}{(1-a)^2} - \dfrac{1}{1-a}$

Here $a=\dfrac{e^t}{2}$